# Play file using SoundJS in Firefox

Tags: firefox, audio, soundjs

I am using [SoundJS](http://www.createjs.com/soundjs) lib to play various mp3/wav files in my web app, however I added a new file but it didn't work at all in FireFox while it is working fine on Chrome. I tried wav/mp3/ogg encoding but none worked with me.
I googled around a little bit but I couldn't find any working solution.
P.S: I have other mp3 files which are working fine in FireFox.

Updated Info:

As response to Dexter I have the following updates:
I am using Firefox 45.0 on Ubuntu 14.04
The console of the browser is:

```
The buffer passed to decodeAudioData contains an unknown content type.
EncodingError: The given encoding is not supported.
```

I tried to use the "mp3info" utility to check the encoding of the file but I got: `background_music.mp3 does not have an ID3 1.x tag.`
using the "file" utiility I got this: `background_music.mp3: MPEG ADTS, layer III, v1, 128 kbps, 44.1 kHz, JntStereo`

P.S: The original file is of "wav" format but using it in FireFox didn't work so I converted it to "mp3" format using "ffmpeg" utility through the command:
`ffmpeg -i input.wav -codec:a libmp3lame -qscale:a 2 background_music.mp3`
This is the output of the command `file input.wav`
`RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, Microsoft PCM, 16 bit, stereo 44100 Hz`

Update2:
I forgot to state that I have other mp3 files that are already working throght FireFox and running the "file" command to one of the files produces the following data:
`file2.mp3: Audio file with ID3 version 2.3.0, contains: MPEG ADTS, layer III, v1, 128 kbps, 44.1 kHz, JntStereo`

Comment: Without too much information about the particular encoding of the mp3 file which is not playing, it's difficult to give a definitive answer. 

It would be very useful to know the output of the browser console when trying to play that file, the version of the browser and your operating system.

Comment: I am using Firefox 45.0 on Ubuntu 14.04 and the output of the browser is:
`The buffer passed to decodeAudioData contains an unknown content type.`
`EncodingError: The given encoding is not supported.`

I don't know how to get the encoding of the file.. if you can show me how that would be appreciated.

Comment: You could probably use the command line utility "mp3info".

Comment: I used the mp3info utility as you suggested and I got `background_music.mp3 does not have an ID3 1.x tag.`

Comment: Please try with the "file" utility as well.

Answer (score 1):

As reported on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats#MP3):

> The MP3 audio format (.mp3, audio/mpeg; distinct from the above MP3 audio in an MP4 container case) is supported in  by Firefox/Firefox for Android/Firefox OS **when the operating system provides an MP3 decoder**, and by Internet Explorer, Chrome and Safari.

The 5th footer note reports:

> To avoid patent issues, support for MP3 is not built directly into Firefox. Instead it relies on support from the OS. Firefox supports this format on the following platforms: Windows Vista+ since Firefox 22.0, Android since Firefox 20.0, Firefox OS since Firefox 15.0, **Linux since Firefox 26.0 (relies on GStreamer codecs)** and OS X 10.7 since Firefox 35.0.

So depending on the mp3 file encoding, you might need to install the restricted gstreamer plugins for Ubuntu.